# Using Susy Scss framework in Mean-stack app

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass

So I just discovered the susy framework to improve my scss files and I would like to use it inside my MEAN-app. I read the documents and followed the instructions. However, I am unable to use it inside my scss file. I followed the following steps:

1. install Susy: npm install susy
2. Make sure sass-loader is installed: npm install sass-loader --save-dev
3. Sass loader enabled in webpack configuration (webpack.confif.common.js):

   module.exports = {
       entry: {
           'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
       },

   ```
   resolve: {
       extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
   },

   module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.html$/,
               use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
           },
           {
               test: /\.css$/,
               use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }]
           },
           {
               test: /\.scss$/,
               use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
           }
       ],
       exprContextCritical: false

   }
   ```

   };
4. Import susy in my app.component.scss: the website states that I should use `@import "~susy/sass/susy";` but that gave me an error so I added a relative path: `@import "../../node_modules/susy/sass/susy";`

**This is what my app.component.scss file looks like now:**

```
@import "SCSS variables/theme-colors";
@import "../../node_modules/susy/sass/susy";


$susy: (
        columns: 16,
        debug: (image: show),
        global-box-sizing: border-sizing
);

$medium-screen: 720px;
$link-color: #330000;

a {
  color: $link-color;

  &:hover {
    color: lighten($link-color, 25%);
  }
}

.container {
  @include container();
}
```

**this is the Error I get **

> cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update
>   app.component.scss:app.component.css
>         error app.component.scss (Line 23: Undefined mixin 'container'.)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Can someone see what I might've done wrong?

Comment: try `@import "~susy/sass/susy";` instead of the whole path.

Comment: I tried the whole path because the @import "~susy/sass/susy"; gave an error

Comment: which version of susy are you using? container mixins were removed from v3 (https://github.com/oddbird/susy/issues/645)

Comment: I'm using the most recent version of Susy. It didn't recognize the span key word as well though, or is that also removed?